# How to show left drawable in AppCompatEditText with passwordToggleEnabled?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an AppCompatEditText when add passwordToggleEnabled="true" my left drawable dissapears. What could be the reason ?

Password EditText Code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

EditText drawable code:

```
_passwordEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(passwordIcon, null, null, null);
```

With app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" :

[image]

Without it:

[image]

Edit: I am able to set drawables on top and bottom but it doesn't work for left and right.

Comment: Is it solved ur problem? I have same issue?

Comment: No ... I created a workaround , to have icons separately. If you solve it please do post the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead of setting null to the existing drawable, get the drawable's and set yours on the left.

```
Drawable[] drawables = _passwordEditText.getCompoundDrawables();

_passwordEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(passwordIcon, drawables[1], drawables[2], drawables[3]);
```

<sup>(Source: example "Icon or button inside Custom Edit Text and its action and click listeners" from Stack Overflow Documentation; copyright 2017 by [Muthukrishnan Rajendran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900128/muthukrishnan-rajendran); licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0. An [archive of the full Stack Overflow Documentation content](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z) can be found at archive.org, in which this example is indexed by topic ID 5843 and example ID 32126.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Muthukrishnan, but it didn't work for me. I am able to set drawables on top and bottom but it doesn't work for left and right.